# JavaScript Regxp: search and replace tags in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need help with some Regexp Javascript/JQuery. I got it working, but I think there is better, simpler solution.

Idea is:
If on `button` click, `target` inner html has tags `<b></b>` anywhere - remove them, else add tag `<b>` at beginning and `</b>` at end.

This is the code: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6WvHg/)

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Bold it"/>
<div id="target">This is <b>sample</b> text</div>


$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){

       var t = $('#target');

         //: search for '</b>' too ???
         var isFound = t.html().search(new RegExp(/<b>/i));

         if(isFound >= 0) //: make 2 replaces into 1 ???
            t.html(t.html().replace(/<b>/,'').replace(/<\/b>/,''))
         else
            t.html('<b>'+t.html()+'</b>')
    })
})
```

Questions are commented in code:

1. How to search for `<b>` and `</b>`
2. Make `.replace(/<b>/,'').replace(/<\/b>/,'')` in one `.replace(/<b>...?..../,'')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something regex is good for, as there's so many ways in which the expression could fail. See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for humorous reasons as to why.
Try using `t.children("b");` to find the instances of `<b>...</b/>` in your tag.

In this case, try the following:

```
t.children("b").each(function() {
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    $(this).replaceWith(contents);
});
```

Or fully expanded:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var t = $('#target');
        t.children("b").each(function() {
            var contents = $(this).contents();
            $(this).replaceWith(contents);
        });
    });
});
```